# Start a Windows service on application level in web application

Tags: asp.net, windows-services

I have a windows service. I want to start the service when my web application starts and will close that service when my application closes.
I searched but I am not getting it. **It should be on application level as It is going to be started only once.** 
The windows service is going to update data in database continuously without any interruption.

Comment: What have you tried? The `System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController` class?

Comment: yes... I know serviceController is the class I need here... But the issue is.. I dont know how will I use that on application level... not on any single web form. I want the service to start with my web app start. and end when my web app end.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Sorry.. I got what I wanted to do.
I didnt know it earlier or say I knew it but I really forgot.
Any thing to start only once in a application life time should be initialized in Application_Start() and then its object can be stored in a application variable to use in any of the pages without worrying about any session. this code block is for a wcf service for example

```
 void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup

        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        MyServiceRef.MyServiceClient myService = new MyServiceRef.MyServiceClient();
        myService.GetData();
        Application["ClientObj"] = myService;
        SqlDependency.Start(constr);

    }
```